# Is there a word for having the need to use the restroom?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

There are words for things like a person's hunger, nausea, anger, etc..

> I'm hungry.
>
> I'm nauseous.
>
> I'm angry.

Is there a similar word for needing to use the bathroom?

> I'm bathroominous.

We're using "bathroomosity" for the time being, but an actual word would be preferable.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a single adjective, when the phrase "I need to use the restroom" is fairly succinct already?

Comment: We're developing a game, and need to have labels for the stats of each person, including their hunger, thirst, nausea, energy, and... bathroomosity, among other things.

Comment: There is no such exact word. The Sims uses "bladder" for the purpose you're describing.

Comment: Even for a neologism *bathroomosity* is not correct. That would describe the degree to which someone was like a bathroom.

Comment: @Jim - How about "bathroomphilic"?

Comment: @JognBogn - for a game, why not just label it ***Urgency***

Comment: Perhaps *toiletric*.

Comment: @HotLicks: Not *-philic*, just *-needic*: *bathroomneedic* or *urinalneedic*.

Comment: @Jim I think urgency is a good single word for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm bursting if you need to pee and I'm desperate if you need to poo.